# Recursive many to many relationship on Rails

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby

For my project, I have some Post linked to Category. What I want to achieve, is to have Category who are relatives to others. Like this :

```
c1 = Category.create(name: 'Television')
c2 = Category.create(name: 'TV')

c1.relatives << c1
```

I use a join table :

```
create_table :category_relative, id: false do |t|
  t.belongs_to :category_1
  t.belongs_to :category_2
end

add_index :category_relative, [:category_1_id, :category_2_id]
```

So far, I have tried this :

```
class Category < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_and_belongs_to_many :relatives, class_name: 'Category',
                      join_table: 'category_relative', foreign_key: 'category_1_id',
                      association_foreign_key: 'category_2_id'
end
```

This is working, but only in a single way :

```
c1.relatives
=> []
c2.relatives
=> [#<Category:0x007fcc610b8418 id: 1, name: 'Television']
```

I know that I can add a relative for each entry, but this is too heavy for my database :

```
c1.relatives << c2
c2.relatives << c1
```

Do you have any idea ? Should I write the JOIN manually ?

Comment: Are you using another table between categories?

Comment: I use a join table 'category_relative' (I edit my answer)

Comment: Have you already solved the question?

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this

```
class Category < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :category_relatives, dependent: :destroy
    has_many :relatives, :through => :category_relative
    has_many :inverse_category_relatives, :class_name => "categoryRelative", :foreign_key => "category_2_id", dependent: :destroy
    has_many :inverse_relatives, :through => :inverse_category_relative, :source => :category
end
```

Through class:

```
class CategoryRelative < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :category
    belongs_to :relative, :class_name => "Category"
end
```

With this code you have a many to many relationship between the same class thourgh another

Comment: I have similar model in an own project it should work

Comment: Do I have to create an other model (CategoryRelative) ?

Comment: Yes with belongs to, I added an I make an edit all has_many must be pluralize

Comment: Looks like it's not working. I can retrieve the relatives from my first category, but not from my second. `c1.category_relatives` retrieve the relatives, but `c2.category_relatives` is empty.

Comment: c1.category_relatives is one relation and the inverse is c2.inverse_category_relatives

Comment: If you want to know all relatives of a category you have to join c1.category_relatives && c2.inverse_category_relatives

Comment: And if you want to access to the c1.relatives.Catogories you have to join c1.relative && c1.inverse_relative

Comment: Well, in this case it's working, but I have to do 2 requests to get my data. Doesn't sound good to me.
The request generated is `SELECT categories.* FROM categories INNER JOIN category_relative ON hashtags.id = category_relative.category_1_id WHERE category_relative.category_2_id = 2`. I should just add `OR category_relative.category_1_id = 2` to my initial request.

Comment: A quick way to solve that is create the inverse relation with the normal create

Comment: when c1.relative << c2 also create c2.relative << c1 (You can do that in the model)

Comment: Define a has_and_belongs_to_many :relatives I think that only defines one navigation. Check this https://www.ruby-forum.com/topic/211511